# How to display picture

Tags: templating

I started working on Craft today. I want to display a background CSS image by adding a rule.

Should I manually copy the file in `assets` folder or there's some way to upload and refer it on page.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the background image to be dynamic and controlled by the client then I would recommend using inline CSS in the template to set the image path. The rest of the required CSS can be in the CSS file itself.

e.g.,

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ entry.image.first().getUrl('transformName') }}')" class="thing" ... >
```

Your CSS file could even have a fallback background-url
and in your CSS

```
.thing { background-size: cover; ... }
```